# Getting zero count in data slices while trying to monitor the data slices using .Net in Azure Data Factory v1

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to monitor the existing Azure data factory pipeline using .NET API. I have been referencing [Microsoft provided .NET API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-copy-activity-tutorial-using-dotnet-api).

Here is the code:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories.Common.Models;

using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System;

namespace ADFv1Tutorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create data factory management client

        //IMPORTANT: specify the name of Azure resource group here
        string resourceGroupName = "<my_resourcegroup_name>";

        //IMPORTANT: the name of the data factory must be globally unique.
        // Therefore, update this value. For example:APITutorialFactory05122017
        string dataFactoryName = "<my data_factory name>";
        DateTime PipelineActivePeriodStartTime = new DateTime(2017, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        DateTime PipelineActivePeriodEndTime = PipelineActivePeriodStartTime.AddYears(10);// AddMinutes(60);
        string Dataset_Destination = "<my dataset_name>";

        TokenCloudCredentials aadTokenCredentials = new TokenCloudCredentials(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubscriptionId"],
                GetAuthorizationHeader().Result);

        Uri resourceManagerUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResourceManagerEndpoint"]);

        DataFactoryManagementClient client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(aadTokenCredentials, resourceManagerUri); 

        Console.WriteLine("Getting run details of a data slice");

        // give it a few minutes for the output slice to be ready
        Console.WriteLine("\nGive it a few minutes for the output slice to be ready and press any key.");
        //Console.ReadKey();

        var datasliceRunListResponse = client.DataSliceRuns.List(
            resourceGroupName,
            dataFactoryName,
            Dataset_Destination,
            new DataSliceRunListParameters()
            {
                DataSliceStartTime = PipelineActivePeriodStartTime.ConvertToISO8601DateTimeString()
            });

        foreach (DataSliceRun run in datasliceRunListResponse.DataSliceRuns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Status: \t\t{0}", run.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("DataSliceStart: \t{0}", run.DataSliceStart);
            Console.WriteLine("DataSliceEnd: \t\t{0}", run.DataSliceEnd);
            Console.WriteLine("ActivityId: \t\t{0}", run.ActivityName);
            Console.WriteLine("ProcessingStartTime: \t{0}", run.ProcessingStartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("ProcessingEndTime: \t{0}", run.ProcessingEndTime);
            Console.WriteLine("ErrorMessage: \t{0}", run.ErrorMessage);
            //var r = run.Properties.Values;
            //run.
            //run.
        }



        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    public static async Task<string> GetAuthorizationHeader()
    {
        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectoryEndpoint"] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectoryTenantId"]);
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationId"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);
        AuthenticationResult result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(
            resource: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WindowsManagementUri"],
            clientCredential: credential);

        if (result != null)
            return result.AccessToken;

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to acquire token");
    }
}
```

}

I have used the correct tenantid, applicationid ,applicationkey and subscriptionid in App.Config file.

I am facing a couple of issues:

1. at code section:

`var datasliceRunListResponse = client.DataSliceRuns.List(
                resourceGroupName,
                dataFactoryName,
                Dataset_Destination,
                new DataSliceRunListParameters()
                {
                    DataSliceStartTime = PipelineActivePeriodStartTime.ConvertToISO8601DateTimeString()
                });`

if I use `datasliceRunListResponse.dataslices.count` 
then **i am getting 0 as data slices count. why**?

2. Another issue is, i want to get the **size of data which has been pulled and pushed by ADF. how do i get that information**?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code earlier and now and I am able to get the count.Just check the start time and dataset name.And also mention the Output Datset only as the slices are attached to it.

```
    string dataFactoryName = "DataFactoryName";
    DateTime PipelineActivePeriodStartTime = new DateTime(2017, 8, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    DateTime PipelineActivePeriodEndTime = DateTime(2017, 10, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    string Dataset_Destination = "Output Dataset Name";



        Console.WriteLine("Getting run details of a data slice");

        Console.WriteLine("\nGive it a few minutes for the output slice to be ready and press any key.");
        //Console.ReadKey();

        var datasliceRunListResponse = client.DataSliceRuns.List(
            resourceGroupName,
            dataFactoryName,
            Dataset_Destination,
            new DataSliceRunListParameters()
            {
                DataSliceStartTime = PipelineActivePeriodStartTime.ConvertToISO8601DateTimeString()
            });
        Console.WriteLine("count is {0}", datasliceRunListResponse.DataSliceRuns.Count()); Console.ReadKey();

        foreach (DataSliceRun run in datasliceRunListResponse.DataSliceRuns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Status: \t\t{0}", run.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("DataSliceStart: \t{0}", run.DataSliceStart);
            Console.WriteLine("DataSliceEnd: \t\t{0}", run.DataSliceEnd);
            Console.WriteLine("ActivityId: \t\t{0}", run.ActivityName);
            Console.WriteLine("ProcessingStartTime: \t{0}", run.ProcessingStartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("ProcessingEndTime: \t{0}", run.ProcessingEndTime);
            Console.WriteLine("ErrorMessage: \t{0}", run.ErrorMessage);
            //var r = run.Properties.Values;
            //run.
            //run.
        }
```